# How to get String from http

Tags: java, jsf-2

I use this code to get integer from the http:

```
this.id = 
 Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
 getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));
```

Now I need to get String from the http. Can you tell me how I can do this? In Netbeans I tested this code:

```
 this.id = 
   String.parseString(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
   getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id"));
```

But I get an error. Can you tell me what is the proper way to do this?

P.S The error in Netbeans:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method parseString(java.lang.String)
  location: class java.lang.String
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: `parseInt` takes a `String` as a parameter, so you already have a `String`. Parsing it as a `String` makes no sense.

Comment: Someone will only tell you the proper way to do this, if you tell us what error you are getting. Without the error, any try will be a blinded shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt` takes a String as a parameter. So you just need:

```
this.id = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().
          getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
```

As you don't need to parse a String to get a String (as your compiler is telling you).

Comment: It turns out that there is a problem. I get null when I try to get a value from. Are you sure that this should work?

Comment: Yep, if the value is null then either it's not being set or you're specifying the wrong key in the `.get(String key)` part.

Answer (score 1):

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id")
```

already return you a String, you dont have to parse it, besides String in Java do not have method:

```
String.parseString(String s)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the .get() returns an object. So you could append .toString() instead of parse it. The upper line returns an Integer object and there you can call .toString() too.
I hope this help...

Answer (score 1):

The String class does not have a parseString() method. You already have a string. This should work (if this.id is in fact a String):

```
   this.id = 
     FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
     getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("id");
```